# AlertDialog not showing in MapsActivity

Tags: java, android, maps

I have a Google Maps Activity in my Android App and it has an AlertDialog that calls the GPS settings when GPS is disabled, but that Dialog isn't showing.

And then what happens is I get a Google Maps activity with no markers because the Dialog didn't ask me to activate GPS.

```
private void openSettingsDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Permissões requeridas");
    builder.setMessage("Esta app precisa de permissões de GPS. Dê essas permissões nas definições.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Definições", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}
```

**This is where I'm calling openSettingsDialog()**

```
private void requestMultiplePermissions() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    // check if all permissions are granted
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Todas as permissões aceites!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // check for permanent denial of any permission
                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                        openSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).
            withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(DexterError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Algum erro ocorreu! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .onSameThread()
            .check();
}
```

**OnCreate()**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        //code for getting current location
        requestMultiplePermissions();

        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv));

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String gpslocation = extras.getString("GPSLocation");
            String[] latLng = gpslocation.split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[1]);
            LatLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
```

[GitHub Link for the Full MapsActivity](https://github.com/manicogaming/PillTrack/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pap/diogo/pilltrack/Maps/MapsActivity.java)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this piece of code, so I think there is a problem with the place where you call this code, can you please tell me where are you calling this function ? maybe update your question and link the hole activity

Comment: The code you have shared does not contain any map related code... Please edit your question with all the information.

Comment: I added the method where I'm calling openSettingsDialog() the code of the whole Activity would be too big to post here.

Comment: @DiogoJesus your code is working, are you calling `requestMultiplePermissions()` in onCreate() ?

Comment: @Amine Yes I am.

Comment: Can you post your onCreate() ?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question and added it.

Answer (score 0):

In openSettingDialogMethod()

remove

```
builder.show();
```

and add this line of code

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: openSettingsDialog() is in a MainActivity class file

Comment: No, it is in the MapsActivity

Comment: Ok, there nothing wrong with this code. Add break point and try to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. Apparently what I wanted wasn't that dialog, it was the Open GPS Settings dialog which I now have it working in my App. Sorry for being a dummy, I'm new in Android Studio.